# Blender Batch Operation - Adding Object to Collection and Save file

Tags: python, asset

I got an asset library and trying to use it with one asset manager add-on. Each asset is under the scene collection. However the asset manager expect them to be part of a collection similar to object name. I wonder if I can automate the below steps with python script. Any support would be highly appreciated.

1. Open the file from a specific folder
2. Read object name under scene collection
3. Create a collection using the object name
4. Move the object in that collection
5. Save the file
6. Repeat until all the files are updated

Thank you!!

==== UPDATE-01 ====

This is what I've found so far. It works with one file at a time.

```
import bpy 
import os

# get filepath
blend_filepath = bpy.data.filepath

# remove extension
blend_filepath = os.path.splitext(blend_filepath)[0]

# get filename
blend_filepath = os.path.basename(blend_filepath)

# Select active object
sel_obj = bpy.context.active_object

# Create new collection with filename and add it as child under scene collection
myCol = bpy.data.collections.new(blend_filepath)
bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(myCol)

C = bpy.context

# List of object references
objs = C.selected_objects

# Set target collection to a known collection
coll_target = C.scene.collection.children.get(blend_filepath)

# If target found and object list not empty
if coll_target and objs:

    # Loop through all objects
    for ob in objs:
        # Loop through all collections the obj is linked to
        for coll in ob.users_collection:
            # Unlink the object
            coll.objects.unlink(ob)

        # Link each object to the target collection
        coll_target.objects.link(ob)

# save blend file
bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile()
```

Comment: So you have one object per file under scene collection and you want that object to be under a collection named as itself ?

Comment: That is correct @Gorgious.

Comment: Posted an update on this question.